# SBT packaging takes long time

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have a scala project with spark dependencies.

These are my dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"                %% "spark-core"                         % "2.2.0"       % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark"                %% "spark-sql"                          % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark"                %% "spark-mllib"                        % "2.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark"                %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl"     % "2.2.0",
  "com.amazonaws"                   %  "amazon-kinesis-client"          % "1.8.7",
  "com.amazonaws"                   %  "aws-java-sdk-dynamodb"          % "1.11.221",
  "com.amazonaws"                   %  "aws-java-sdk"                   % "1.11.221",
  "com.amazonaws"                   %  "aws-java-sdk-core"              % "1.11.221",
  "com.amazonaws"                   %  "aws-java-sdk-sts"               % "1.11.221",
  "org.json4s"                      %% "json4s-jackson"                     % "3.2.11",
  "org.json4s"                      %% "json4s-core"                    % "3.2.11",
  "com.maxmind.geoip2"              %  "geoip2"                             % "2.9.0",
  "com.maxmind.db"                  %  "maxmind-db"                         % "1.2.2",
  "org.uaparser"                    %% "uap-scala"                      % "0.2.0",
  "org.elasticsearch"               %% "elasticsearch-spark-20"             % "5.6.5",
  "com.google.guava"                %  "guava"                          % "23.2-jre",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"      % "jackson-core"                % "2.9.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"      % "jackson-databind"                % "2.9.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"      % "jackson-annotations"                 % "2.9.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-cbor"            % "2.9.1",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11"          % "2.9.1",
  "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.1.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % Test,
  "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "2.2.0_0.8.0" % Test
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case _ => MergeStrategy.last
}
```

If I am running sbt assembly, it usually takes 20min. sbt clean and sbt test is fine. It hangs up at the packaging part. I tried with a very basic project as well with less dependencies, and it also takes 20min to assembly. I am using SBT 0.13.16 and Scala 2.11.11.

Please see my *jstack*:

```
    "Attach Listener" #488 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eba057000 nid=0x1417 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ForkJoinPool-2-worker-15" #301 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8ebc8fe000 nid=0xc617 waiting on condition [0x0000700014e2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007846ff178> (a scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner" #139 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8ebb88a000 nid=0xb803 in Object.wait() [0x00007000130d8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x00000007846e5958> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:3212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Timer-0" #78 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8ebc660800 nid=0x631b in Object.wait() [0x0000700010454000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
    - locked <0x0000000784587de0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

"ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9" #69 daemon prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb8b4b800 nid=0x6d03 waiting on condition [0x0000700010b69000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007834aea88> (a scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:2075)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

"pool-6-thread-1" #53 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb36db800 nid=0x5a17 runnable [0x0000700010047000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:73)
    at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:73)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$2.openImpl(Using.scala:65)
    at sbt.OpenFile$class.open(Using.scala:43)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:64)
    at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:64)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:23)
    at sbt.IO$.transfer(IO.scala:319)
    at sbt.IO$.sbt$IO$$addFileEntry$1(IO.scala:513)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$sbt$IO$$writeZip$2.apply(IO.scala:521)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$sbt$IO$$writeZip$2.apply(IO.scala:521)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at sbt.IO$.sbt$IO$$writeZip(IO.scala:521)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$archive$1.apply(IO.scala:477)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$archive$1.apply(IO.scala:475)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$withZipOutput$1.apply(IO.scala:565)
    at sbt.IO$$anonfun$withZipOutput$1.apply(IO.scala:552)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.IO$.withZipOutput(IO.scala:552)
    at sbt.IO$.archive(IO.scala:475)
    at sbt.IO$.jar(IO.scala:459)
    at sbt.Package$.makeJar(Package.scala:102)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.sbtassembly$Assembly$$makeJar$1(Assembly.scala:40)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Assembly.scala:79)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Assembly.scala:75)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$outputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:84)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$outputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:79)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:83)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:245)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:242)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2017800 nid=0x5303 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4008800 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb200b000 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4007800 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4006000 nid=0x4b03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4005000 nid=0x4903 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4037800 nid=0x3903 in Object.wait() [0x000070000f782000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000780009778> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4034800 nid=0x3703 in Object.wait() [0x000070000f67f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x0000000780018398> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb3001800 nid=0x1c03 waiting on condition [0x000070000ec5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000780a52898> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.take(ExecutorCompletionService.java:193)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:188)
    at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:85)
    at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:88)
    at sbt.Execute.runKeep(Execute.scala:68)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.liftedTree1$1(EvaluateTask.scala:359)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:358)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:378)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:69)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:67)
    at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:314)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.timedRun(Aggregation.scala:67)
    at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:76)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:37)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:36)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:158)
    at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:157)
    at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:253)
    at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:250)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:183)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:187)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:61)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

"VM Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4030000 nid=0x3503 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2010800 nid=0x2503 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2011000 nid=0x2703 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2011800 nid=0x2903 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2012800 nid=0x2b03 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2013000 nid=0x2d03 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2013800 nid=0x2f03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2014000 nid=0x3103 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb2015000 nid=0x3303 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=31 tid=0x00007f8eb4039800 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition 

   JNI global references: 342
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Please upgrade to the most recent [sbt 1.1.0](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) and report back. It has fixed a lot of performance issues and is supposed to be way faster.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Have the Spark compatibility issues been resolved?

Comment: What are they (except `run` that I think should work fine in 1.1.0)?

Comment: Thanks @JacekLaskowski Unfortunately it still takes 15min to build. The weird thing is that my team members can build this project in 2min.

Comment: That pretty much makes it not really Spark, doesn't it, so removing the tag (and leaving it in sbt's hands).